# How much choice is required to prove concretizability theorems in category theory?

Tags: ct.category-theory, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

A *concretization* of a  category is a faithful  functor  to  the category of sets. A category is *concretizable* if there exists such a functor.

An evident necessary condition for concretizability is local smallness. Of course, for many local smallness is part of the definition of category.  In the 1960s, Isbell exhibited a further necessary condition and conjectured its sufficiency.

The following theorems  were established in the early 1970s:

1) (Freyd) Isbell's necessary condition for concretizability is sufficient.

2) (Kučera) Every category is a quotient  of a concretizable category by a congruence.

Precise definitions, statements, and  proofs may be found in Chapter 6 of "Theory of Mathematical Structures" by Adámek. These results are formulated in the language of class-set theory and proved in GB+Global Choice. The arguments rely on having an appropriate well-ordering of the class of all sets.

Another result from the same period is:

3) (Freyd) The Homotopy Category is not concretizable.

By definition, this category is a quotient of a concretizable category. Here the evident weakening to a schema (asserting that no formula yields a concretization) is  formalizable in the language of set theory, and the argument appears to carry over as well.

Are the evident weakenings of assertions 1) and 2) to schemata (for definable categories, concretizations and congruences) provable in ZFC?

Comment: Could you add precise statements or precise references?

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais, the Isbell condition was formulated in "Two set-theoretical theorems in categories" by Isbell (http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm53/fm5315.pdf), and the Freyd's theorem is stated in "CONCRETENESS" by Freyd (http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022404973900315), though I don't think the question is interesting...

Comment: These results are discussed in Chapter 6 of "Theory of Mathematical Structures" by Adámek. The arguments rely on having an appropriate well-ordering of the class of all sets. Freyd also showed that the Homotopy Category is not concretizable. Here it is evident by definition that this category is a quotient of a concretizable category. Those arguments seem formalizable in ZFC

Comment: @DavidRoberts  I've just now noticed the following reference to work that must surely clarify the issued raised.

https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2021/07/large_sets_125.html#c060315

Perhaps you could post an answer in light of this?

Comment: @Adam not sure how I missed this. Yes, 1) and 2) are theorems in ZF (say relativised, or for definable locally small categories) or NBG minus choice; 2) is definitely a theorem even in a slightly weaker version of Algebraic Set Theory assuming the category of classes is boolean. I believe so is 1), if we add in an axiom about a cumulative hierarchy that always holds for ZF.

Comment: @DavidRoberts My (by now vague) recollection of  Freyd's proof of 1 is that Choice was all over the place. But perhaps this cleans up nice?

Comment: @AdamEpstein yes, it does!

Comment: For now, see the slides at the end of this blog post https://thehighergeometer.wordpress.com/2022/01/13/how-to-be-concrete-when-you-dont-have-a-choice/

Comment: @DavidRoberts "Unfortunately the original proof starts by well-ordering the universe of sets, which really makes me itch"

^ This

Comment: @DavidRoberts What does it mean (in material set-theoretic terms) for the universe to admit a linear preorder that is a small relation? Does this follow from ZF, or is it Choice assumption?

Comment: @Adam it [follows from](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity#Every_set_has_an_ordinal_rank) the axiom of Foundation (and Pairing), which gives the von Neumann rank function $rk\colon V\to ORD$, and the induced preorder on $V$ from the well-order on $ORD$ is small, in that for every set $x$, the subclass of elements of $V$ that are have rank $\leq rk(x)$ is a set. But more generally, _any_ hierarchy stratification of $V$ will do, it doesn't have to be the von Neumann one. There are material set theories weaker than ZF where an "axiom of rank" is postulated, and this is enough.

Comment: @DavidRoberts Being a great fan of Scott's Trick, I figured that ranks were involved, but I'm a bit surprised that they only need to be linearly, rather than well ordered.

Comment: Set-like linear orders ("small" in AST parlance) and well-ordered classes are kind of orthogonal generalisations of well-ordered sets, mind. $ORD+ORD$ is well-ordered, but not set-like, and _any_ linearly-ordered set is clearly set-like (eg the rationals, with the usual order).

Comment: @DavidRoberts Is this setting sufficient to show that for any equivalence relation there exists a function which is constant on equivalence classes?

(Domain and range of relations are meant to be subclasses of the universal class - not sure whether or not this is baked into the AST formalism).

Comment: @DavidRoberts Also in "Yes, 1) and 2) are theorems in ZF (say relativised, or for definable locally small categories)" what does "relativised" mean? I'm guessing it means augmenting the signature with a predicate symbol and allowing its appearance in Separation and Replacement axioms.

Comment: @DavidRoberts With regard to functions constant on equivalence classes, one might desire them to be definable from the equivalence relation.

Comment: @Adam I think I meant relativised to a given model of ZF. Getting a function constant on equivalence classes is easy: take a constant function! Getting on that takes distinct values on different equivalence classes is trickier. I think you need the ranks to be well-ordered, or some other mechanism that avoids choices to find sets of representatives of all equivalence classes.

Comment: @DavidRoberts  Yes, injective :) In my view, the ability to simulate quotients of large equivalence relations on the universe is fundamental to a certain conception of sets. (How else to discuss cardinal numbers as first class objects?) I don't see that this is supported in systems such as ETCS (with which I have some familiarity), but my impression is that the conception in AST (which which I far less familiarity) is more robustly analogous to the (materially formulated) picture in ZF. Has this sort of matter been treated there?

Comment: @DavidRoberts I'd be happy to accept an answer based on your comments.

Comment: @Adam, Ok, I'll cobble something together tomorrow. I'm off to bed... sorry for not yet answering the question in your previous comment.