# There are no abstract categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, set-theory

$\newcommand\Set{\mathbf{Set}}\newcommand\Ob{\mathbf{Ob}}\newcommand\Hom{\mathbf{Hom}}$Work in a foundation that admits a countable hierarchy of notions of ‘set’, and say that a category is *$n$-small* iff its object and arrow collections are $n$-sets. Denote the category of $n$-sets by $\Set_n$.

For each $n$-small category $\mathcal{C}$ and each object $X\in\Ob_\mathcal{C}$, define
\begin{gather*}
\Hom_\mathcal{C}(\ \ ,X)=\operatorname{cod}^{-1}(X)\subseteq\Hom_\mathcal{C} \\
\Bigl({}=\bigcup_{W\in\Ob_\mathcal{C}}\Hom_\mathcal{C}(W,X)\Bigr).
\end{gather*}
For each $n$-small category $\mathcal{C}$, define a functor
\begin{gather*}
\Hom_\mathcal{C}(\ \ ,-):\mathcal{C}\to\Set_{n+1} \\
X\mapsto\Hom_\mathcal{C}(\ \ ,X) \\
f:X\to Y\longmapsto {f\circ{}}:\Hom_\mathcal{C}(\ \ ,X)\to\Hom_\mathcal{C}(\ \ ,Y).
\end{gather*}
$\Hom_\mathcal{C}(\ \ ,-)$ is always faithful, so $n$-small categories are never abstract. Working in an appropriate foundation (see [An axiomatic approach to higher order set theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/2206.10060) (disclaimer: I am the author of this paper)) all classically considered ‘abstract’ categories like Freyd's homotopy category are just $0$-large $1$-small categories, admitting canonical faithful functors into $\Set_2$.

Taking this view, it seems like categories are only ‘abstract’ if we work in a set-theoretical foundation that is ‘too small’ to see the larger categories of sets that all categories embed into. This makes me wonder,

> Are there any categories we care about that remain abstract in set theories admitting a countable hierarchy of notions of ‘set’? What if we extend the hierarchy of notions of set to arbitrary ordinal heights?

Comment: In fact even more is true than Simon's answer: every *locally small category* is a quotient (by a congruence on its hom-sets, much like the classical homotopy category) of a concrete category. This was a result of Kučera in NBG (incl global choice), but Martti Karvonen and I have reduced it to work in Algebraic Set Theory with EM (no preprint yet, but I've given talks about it)

Comment: @DavidRoberts Very (!!!) cool! I think you and I actually had an exchange on here about that original result a few years back, I’d be very interested to hear more about the developments you’ve been collaborating on.

Comment: @DavidRoberts [Found it](https://mathoverflow.net/a/361959/92164)! (and it looks like I actually introduced you to the result originally; small world heh)

Comment: This IMO shows that the definition of *concreteness* as a property is reduced to a constraint on the size of the category, and therefore is not the correct notion. A concrete categorie should be a category *equipped* with a faithful functor to Set, i.e. it is a structure instead of a property.

Comment: @AlecRhea oh, that's funny :-) I'll send you an email with more details about the newer work.

Comment: @DavidRoberts Much appreciated.

Comment: @Alec I used your ResearchGate email, I hope that's current. If not, my nLab page will get you mine.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The argument you give in your original post is essentially the proof that *every small category is concrete.*

So if you work in a setting that have enough universes/inaccessible cardinal/notion of smallness so that it is reasonable to only consider "small" categories, then of course all categories are concrete.

However, as soon as you allow yourself to form something like the category of *all* sets, you will get examples of non-concrete categories:

The typical examples of non-concrete categories are the category of all groupoids with isomorphism classes of functors between them. Or the homotopy category of all spaces/simplicial sets.

So unless you insist on only talking about small categories (which definitely make sense in some foundation), you'll always get examples of non-concrete categories.

But I would add that even if you consider that "all categories are small", a better point of view on concreteness is that, (like for smallness) one shouldn't talk about "concrete categories" in the abstract but of $n$-concrete categories exactly as you talked about $n$-small sets. Even in settings where everything is small in some sense, the notion of smallness is still relevant: for e.g. the category of $n$-small sets isn't closed under all $m$-small colimits for $m>n$. So even in a setting where every category is concrete in some sense, the notion of concreteness could still be relevant.

Comment: Heh, “‘concrete categories’ in the abstract”.  As opposed to concrete examples of abstract categories, probably.  

Comment: Yes, bad choice of words instead !  Though, if you think about it, the point I was trying to make is that concreteness is not an abstract notion ^^