# Is any elementary topos a concretizable category?

Tags: ct.category-theory, topos-theory

The following special cases are obvious:

1. A Grothendieck topos is concretizable ($F \mapsto \times_i F(i)$)
2. A well-pointed topos is concretizable ($X \mapsto \rm{Hom}(1, X)$)

I looked at some more different examples and they are all obviously concretizable (but I'm just starting to learn topos theory). Is there an elementary topos from which there is no faitfull functor to the category of sets?

Comment: Actually, a well-pointed topos may fail to be concretisable if it is not locally small. Or are you implicitly assuming size conditions here?

Comment: Because regular subobjects form a set, every elementary topos is concretizable by the lazy Isbell criterion. Check Freyd's papers on concreteness.

Comment: @ZhenLin I meant local-small, yes

Comment: @IvanDiLiberti Indeed, thank you very much! You can post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I wrote down the answer (as a community wiki). If you post yours, I'll accept it and delete mine.

Comment: (Obviously, every non-locally small category is not concretizable, so the question only makes sense for locally small ones)

Comment: Which categories are concretizable [depends on the foundation you work in](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/432071/there-are-no-abstract-categories); it can be argued that all categories are concretizable under an appropriate ‘change of foundation’.

Comment: @AivazianArshak, thanks but I do not need points. I am happy to have been of help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As Ivan Di Liberti suggests in the comments, according to Lemma 1.2 ([Freyd's paper, *Concretness*](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-4049(73)90031-5), JPAA 1973) every regular well-powered category with equalizers is concretizable. In particular, every locally small elementary topos is concretizable.